# Addition of two elements in a field with four elements

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I have just started out learning about fields and had tried practicing solving some questions. However, when I encountered this question, I wasn't really sure how to tackle it.

> Let $\mathbb{F} = \{0,1,a,b\}$ be a field with four elements.
>   
> Prove that $1 + 1 = 0$.

I wanted to show that $1 + 1 = a$, $ 1 + 1 = 1$, and $1 + 1 = b$ would all result in a contradiction. So, I started with supposing that $1+1= a$.

Since I have already proved that $a \cdot b =1$, $a^2=b$, and $b^2=a$, I thought about using at least one of these pieces of information to arrive at a contradiction, but I can't seem to figure how to use them in this case.

In the question, a hint is also given which suggests showing how assuming that $1+1 =a $ will let us make use of $1+a$ and $1+b$ to arrive at $a^2 =0$, which is impossible. But I can't seem to understand how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the field with four elements, $1+a=b$ and $1+b=a$.  Adding these together, $1+1+a+b=a+b$.  Therefore, $1+1=0$.

Comment: The easiest I know would be invoking Lagrange's thm.  Since the addition makes $\Bbb F$ a group of order $4$, $1+1+1+1=0$ must hold.  If $1+1\ne 0$, then $1+1$ is a zero divisor, since $$(1+1)(1+1)=1+1+1+1=0.$$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how were you able to conclude that $1+1+a+b = a+b$?

Comment: @HarryBattersby:  I added $1+a=b$ and $1+b=a$ to get $(1+a)+(1+b)=b+a$ and then used the commutative property of addition

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm sorry for these silly questions, but how did it exactly help you deduce that $1+1=0?$ Could you perhaps elaborate a little?

Comment: @HarryBattersby:  $1+1+a+b=a+b\implies 1+1=0$ because of subtracting $a+b$ from both sides (is that what you were asking?)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I claim that $1+a=b$.

For if $1+a=0$, then $a=-1$ so $a^2=1$, but you proved $a^2=b$;

if $1+a=1$, then $a=0, $ a contradiction;

and if $1+a=a$, then $1=0$, a contradiction.

A similar argument proves that $1+b=a$.

Adding $1+a=b$ and $1+b=a$ yields $(1+a)+(1+b)=b+a$

or $1+1+a+b=a+b$ (using commutativity of addition),

which implies (subtracting $a+b$ from both sides) that $1+1=0$.

Quod erat demonstrandum.